# jQuery calculate number of list items, then multiply that by number and set as width

Tags: jquery, width

I'm trying to set a dynamic width to `ul.sections` by checking how many `li's` exist and multiply that by the width of the `li` (`$("ul.sections").width()`), which in this case happens to be 910px.

I'm not sure how to return the current number of visible list items. Maybe something like this?

```
$('ul.sections').width($("ul.sections li").length() * $("ul.sections li").width());
```

Which obviously doesn't work yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.length` is a property not a method, so just use `$("ul.sections li").length` like this:

```
$('ul.sections').width($("ul.sections li").length * $("ul.sections").width());
```

If you have multiple sections, this would be the jQuery 1.4+ version:

```
$('ul.sections').width(function(i, w) { return $(this).find('li').length * w; });
```

Comment: Thank you, this was correct. I should have left off the `()`. I thought I was far off with the rest of it, but I was pretty close! Finally getting the hang of slightly intermediate jQuery yessss :)

Answer (score 1):

there is a [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) jQuery Selector

to get all visible `<li>`'s in ul.sections

```
$("ul.sections li:visible")
```

so now you can set your width

```
$("ul.sections").width($("ul.sections li:visible").length * $("ul.sections").width()));
```

Comment: I forgot to add the :visible selector before, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

use `size()`

http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Both `size()` and `.length` return the proper numeral. Thanks.